# Need script to click webelement x, y using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

In Selenium, we use action to click on element with X and Y

```
action.MoveToElement(element, X, Y).Click().Build().Perform()
```

I need to attain this functionality using Javascript.
Is it possible in JS.

Comment: If you searched properly you'd get `document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();`

Comment: The above action command get x, y coordinate from the element(WebElement). But in document.elementFromPoint, where I need to pass webelement.

Comment: You don't. If there is an element on that point then `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` will return the element and `.click()` is the function to perform click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {'view': window,'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true,'clientX': arguments[0].getClientRects()[0].left + arguments[1],'clientY': arguments[0].getClientRects()[0].top + arguments[2]}))",element, offsetX, offsetY);
```

Code from [Selenide Framework](https://selenide.org). 
Details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent